# In $n$ dimensions, why do we need at least $n+1$ sample points to have covariance of sample data non-singular?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

In $n$ dimensions, why do we need at least $n+1$ sample points to have covariance of sample data non-singular?

[image]

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479483/when-does-the-inverse-of-a-covariance-matrix-exist